# How can we predict target values for new data, based on a different dataset? scikit learn / gaussianNB

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I am struggling to understand how training our algorithms connects with making predictions on new data.
My situation: I have an algorithm that I use on a labeled dataset. After the steps of importing it, encoding it, fit_transforming it and fitting it to make predictions on the data_test of the train_test_split function I get a really nice prediction from using the labeled dataset.
I am stumped as to how I need to feed a new dataset (unlabeled this time) to the trained model, which has learned from the labeled dataset. I know that technically the data used to train withheld the labels from itself to predict, but I am unaware how I have to provide the gaussianNB algorithm new data features to predict unknown labels.

My code for the training:

```
df = pd.read_csv(chosen_file, sep=',')
cat_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
cat_cols_filled = cat_cols.fillna('0')
le = LabelEncoder()
cat_cols_fitted = cat_cols_filled.apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col))
non_cat_cols = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
non_cat_cols_filled = non_cat_cols.fillna('0')
non_cat_cols_fitted = non_cat_cols_filled.apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col))
target_prep = df.iloc[:,-1]
target = le.fit_transform(target_prep.astype(str))
data = pd.concat([cat_cols_fitted, non_cat_cols_fitted], axis=1)
try:
    data_train, data_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(data, target, train_size=0.3))
alg = GaussianNB()
pred = alg.fit(data_train, target_train).predict(***data_test***)
```

This is all fine and dandy. But I cannot understand how I have to give something in place of ***data_test***. Do I need to provide the new dataset with some placeholder values for the label column? My label column from the beginning dataframe is the last one.

My attempt:

```
new_df = pd.read_csv(new_chosen_file, sep=',')
new_cat_cols = new_df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
new_cat_cols_filled = new_cat_cols.fillna('0')
new_cat_cols_fitted = new_cat_cols_filled.apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col))
new_non_cat_cols = new_df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
new_non_cat_cols_filled = new_non_cat_cols.fillna('0')
new_non_cat_cols_fitted = new_non_cat_cols_filled.apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col))
new_data = pd.concat([new_cat_cols_fitted, new_non_cat_cols_fitted], axis=1)
print(new_data)
new_pred = alg.predict(new_data)
new_prediction = pd.DataFrame({'NEW ML prediction':new_pred})
print(new_pred)
print(new_prediction)
```

Notice I do not provide the target column in the new dataset. However the program errors out on me if I my column count does not match, so I am forced to add at least the label for the column for it to not do that:
[image: traceback error]

Am I way off in my understanding of how this works? Please let me know.

EDIT:

I found my major screw-up in the code. I had not isolated my target column out of the data DataFrame. This was why data was 10 column shape.
I can finally appreciate the simplicity of the code.

Comment: **Notice I do not provide the target column in the new dataset**. When you train your model, you should not include target column in the *data_train* set

Comment: @akhetos how do I do that? When the convention is:
data_train, data_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(data, target, train_size=0.3))
If I don't provide the target - no predictions can be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating an empty model to `alg`. Returning the prediction from fitted model to a variable named `pred`. So you are not actually saving the fitted model.

The concatenation of multiple methods such as
`alg.fit(data_train, target_train).predict(***data_test***)` is known as method chaining and can cause confusion.

A cleaner & more readable alternative is to :

```
alg = GaussianNB()                       # initiating model
alg = alg.fit(data_train, target_train)  # fitting model with train data
pred = alg.predict(***data_test***)      # testing with test data
new_pred = alg.predict(new_data)         # test with new data`
```

Comment: but pred is a numpy.ndarray object, so it has no attribute 'predict'.

Comment: so in order to predict new unlabeled data -  all I was missing was to use the algorithm object, fitted with training data not the algorithm by itself, correct?
Also, wouldn't like 2 (your example) be better understood as:
alg_fit = alg.fit(data_train, target_train) ? Because now it seems like we've redeclared the gaussianNB() object

Comment: Yes. You were not saving the trained model to a variable. You were saving the result from the prediction which is a numpy array to 'pred'. So when you called alg.predict(new_data) , you are actually calling an empty alg object.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You can even insantiate & fit the model in one line. ie : 
alg = GaussianNB().fit(data_train, target_train). This will still return the trained model to alg. However, the predict function will not return the trained model, it will return the resulting prediction as a numpy array. Hope it is clear now. :)

Comment: One more thing - why does my new dataset need to include the target column name? Without it I get the error in the picture I provided in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197205/discussion-between-rakidedigama-and-vaidotas-ivoska).